# SharePoint Online, deploy module in non-root Site Collection(how to load JS dynamically correctly)?

Tags: javascript, module

For example I have a solution with three files in module:

[image]

**Loader.html**:

```
<div id="exampleDiv" style="background-color: yellowgreen">click here..</div>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../Style%20Library/TestSpSOD/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../Style%20Library/TestSpSOD/consoleHello.js"></script>
```

**jQuery**
and my javascript file, **addClickEvent.js**:

```
"use strict";

function addClickEvent() {
    jQuery("#exampleDiv").on("click", function () { (alert("Hello!")) });
}

// if scripts are loaded from hardcoded root site collection
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("addClickEvent");
```

I refer this script in CEWP on root site collection like

> /sites/SiteColection/Style Library/TestSpSOD/Loader.html

and all this works.

But it will not work on subsites, I need to write something like "src="**../../**../Style%20Library/TestSpSOD/consoleHello.js" and change the path every time

I want to load jQuery.js and my javascript file dynamically:

```
<div id="exampleDiv" style="background-color: yellowgreen">click here..</div>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    function moduleLoader() {

        var url = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + "/Style%20Library/TestSpSOD/";

        var jqueryScript = document.createElement('script');
        jqueryScript.src = url + "jquery-3.1.1.min.js";
        jqueryScript.type = "text/javascript";
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jqueryScript);

        var myScript = document.createElement('script');
        myScript.src = url + "consoleHello.js";
        myScript.type = "text/javascript";
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(myScript);
    }

    // if scripts are loaded dynamically
    //
        SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(moduleLoader, 'sp.js');
    //
    </script>
```

But than my **_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("addClickEvent");** does not work. Also if I check this code in FF it sometimes says "jQuery not defined", and sometimes doesn't say it. Also tried to do something like

```
    // if scripts are loaded dynamically
    SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(moduleLoader, 'sp.js');
    SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(addClickEvent, 'sp.js');
```

but it does not work.

How to load these scripts correctly?

**upd.:** Thank You all guys for answers! All of them are very interesting! I used method that Cecilia reccomended (added loading html and css):

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    var url = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/Style%20Library/TestSpSOD/";

    // add html markup
    document.write("<div id='exampleDiv'>");
    document.write("click here..");
    document.write("<\/div>");

    // add css
    document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' type='text\/css' href='" + url + "" + "\/styles\/stylesheet.css'><\/script>");

    // add js
    document.write("<script src='" + url + "jquery-3.1.1.min.js'><\/script>");
    document.write("<script src='" + url + "addClickEvent.js'><\/script>");

    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () {
        addClickEvent();
    }, "sp.js");

</script>
```

It works on root and on subwebs on my dev and test and in the cloud (Mohamed Derhalli commented that using  will break MDS if it's used). Now I don't need to change code every time

Comment: Is your feature Web or Site scoped ?

Comment: Site scoped. Think it should be Site-Scoped. If I switch to Web-scoped then this feature will try to search "Style Library" on child web, but there is no "Style Library" on child web.

Comment: Note that ``document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]`` is '*I don't know Jack about the DOM*' code for ``document.head`` ... it was needed in IE8 because Microsoft is always late with implementing standards

Comment: Thank You all very much for great answers! I will play with all the tips you provided and keep you posted! Suggested it is asynchronious but didn't think it it so.. nontrivial to load js scripts in SharePoint.. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if this is not the best method to link the js files, I think you could replace the *webServerRelativeUrl* property with *siteAbsoluteUrl* like this:

```
var url = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/Style%20Library/TestSpSOD/";
```

Instead of appending a child to the header you can directly write on the document like this:

```
document.write("<script src='" + url + "jquery-3.1.1.min.js'><\/script>");
document.write("<script src='" + url + "addClickEvent.js'><\/script>");
```

and call your custom functions like this:

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () {
    moduleLoader();
    addClickEvent();
}, "sp.js");
```

Or you can use another solution like this:

```
<div id="exampleDiv" style="background-color: yellowgreen">click here..</div>

<script type='text/javascript'>

    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () {

        var url = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/Style%20Library/TestSpSOD/";

        SP.SOD.registerSod("addClickEvent.js", url + "addClickEvent.js");
        SP.SOD.registerSod("jquery-3.1.1.min.js", url + "jquery-3.1.1.min.js");

        //Tell SOD to load jquery first
        SP.SOD.registerSodDep("addClickEvent.js", "jquery-3.1.1.min.js");

        SP.SOD.executeFunc('addClickEvent.js', null, function () {
            //This will run, but not until SP loads its jquery dependency!
            addClickEvent();
        });

    }, "sp.js");

</script>
```

Comment: Note that referencing scripts using `<script>` will break MDS if it's used.

Comment: Cecilia thanks much for great answer! First method works like a charm, in all environments! :) I'll update my question with Your answer

Answer (score 2):

The sure way to get scriptfiles loaded is to load them as UserCustomAction ScriptLinks

See all ScriptLink posts here on SO: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/search?q=scriptlink

This technique has been around since SP2010, yet most blogs continue with SOD  or stuffing links in the MasterPage

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-sp-editor/ecblfcmjnbbgaojblcpmjoamegpbodhd

Is a Chrome Browser extension that helps you assign Site or Web Scoped ScriptLinks without any coding (you only need to do this once)

These scripts load way before most SharePoint scriptfiles, so great for jQuery and the like scripts.

Note that JSLink on SharePoint Online can also reference **any** https link, so you could use a JSLink setting on a WebPart as well to load jQuery from a CDN
Files in JSLink connections are loaded fairly late, check the `head` of any page

All this stuff does **not** work on the new Modern Experiences,
Microsofts "We are working" on it response, has **not** changed since May 2nd
You can cast your "*C'mmon Microsoft, you gotta fix this!!!*" vote here:

https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/13385364-allow-javascript-customization-and-css-branding-th

Comment: Thank You Danny for answer! I have voted :) In my case I try to use csripts only in my webpart and do not affect the entire page. Thanks for chrome extension link. I knew only about "Cisar" extension by Andrey Markeev before: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cisar/nifbdojdggkboiifaklkamfpjcmgafpo (it allows to add custom CSR as I understand)

Comment: https://github.com/andrei-markeev/cisar

Comment: Cisar is the best thing since sliced bread. It inspired me to create a DEV environment using 100% browser only technologies for the upcoming SPFx release

Answer (score 1):

If you want to dynamically load your scripts into CEWP and don't want to load them for every page of the site (JSLink) you can use one of the following approaches.

Let me first explain why your code doesn't work.

All scripts you are adding after page load with `document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(myScript);` by default are loaded **asynchronously**.

That's very easy to check - create a file `index.html`:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var s = document.createElement("script");
            s.setAttribute("src","script.js");
            document.head.appendChild(s);
            console.log("done");
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Inside `script.js` put `console.log('Hi')`. Output will be `done hi`.
That's why **sometimes** jquery is undefined for you - when the `consoleHello.js` loads before jquery (because of async nature explained above).

Now approaches:

- Use [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) to get your file and provide `text` property instead of `src`:

```js
// get some kind of XMLHttpRequest
var xhrObj = createXMLHTTPObject();
xhrObj.open('GET', "script.js");
xhrObj.send();
.....
// add the returned content to a newly created script tag
var se = document.createElement('script');
se.type = "text/javascript";
se.text = xhrObj.responseText;
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(se);
```

You need to load your scripts one by one or simultaneously, but add jquery to document first.

- set `async=false` for script tag:

```js
function loadScriptSync (src) {
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.src = src;
    s.type = "text/javascript";
    s.async = false;                                 // <-- this is important
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
}
```

**Caveats**: sync loading is generally bad idea in modern web development. IE9 and below doesn't support `async`

- In the past I've created my own async script loader. Here the full code:

```js
var JSLoader = function (pathToScript, successCallback) {
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.async = true;
        script.type = "text/javascript";
        script.src = pathToScript;
        var loaded = false;
        var succcessFunction = successCallback;
        this.load = function () {
            script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if ((script.readyState && script.readyState !== "complete" && script.readyState !== "loaded") || loaded) {
                    return;
                }
                loaded = true;
                script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = null;

                if (succcessFunction && typeof succcessFunction === "function") {
                    succcessFunction();
                }
            };
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
            s.parentNode.insertBefore(script, s);
        };
};
```

Sample using (in your case):

```js
var jqloader = new JSLoader(_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + "/Style%20Library/TestSpSOD/jquery.js", function () {
    // jquery loaded! Let the party begin! :)
    new JSLoader(_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + "/Style%20Library/TestSpSOD/consoleHello.js").load();
});
jqloader.load();
```

Comment: Thank You much for the answer! Interesting! What I noticed that if I use Your JSLoader and there are few CEWP webparts on the page - it breaks the others (if they load js in 'standard way' using <script src="..">)

Comment: Right, that's common problem. Ideally you should use some of the module systems (ie. CommonJS or AMD), and use module bundlers (webpack, browserify, etc.) in order to build isolated bundle without polluting global scope.